# Google map iframe issue

Tags: html, iframe, dictionary

I have embedded Google map using iframe; map shows a pin point when clicking on it a address window is opened. How to set this window opened by default
http://demo.coregenie.com/walltech/contact-us/

Comment: I don't see that you use an `iframe` at the linked page at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [google's info window displayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple); from this, you can use the code `infowindow.open(map,marker);` to automatically open the `infowindow` using

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

:)